# Getting The error like "env: node\r: No such file or directory" when i am trying to run the MIgrations scripts in Node js Project

Tags: node.js

Command I tried:

```
npx knex migrate:latest
```

Error Message:

> "env: node\r: No such file or directory"
> KnexPackage version : v2.4.0

When I am using lower version of knex (1.0.7) it's working as expected, but the latest version is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

This should've been fixed in the [2.4.2 release](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/5455#issuecomment-1399500712). Maybe next time it might be better to open an issue directly in the repo in case of an issue like this one :)